# Custom Global Hotkey

Tags: c, winapi, global, registerhotkey

I am trying to get the user defined global hot key for my application. Here is my application code,

**user.rc**

```
CONTROL         "", IDC_MHOTKEY, HOTKEY_CLASS, WS_TABSTOP, 91, 86, 68, 14
```

**function.cpp**

```
    WORD wHotKey = SendDlgItemMessage(hwnd, IDC_MHOTKEY, HKM_GETHOTKEY, 0, 0);
    GLOBAL_HOTKEY= wHotKey;
    RegisterHotKey ( NULL, TURN_OFF_HOTKEY, HIBYTE(LOWORD(wHotKey)) , wHotKey);
```

**main.cpp**

```
   if ( messages.message == WM_HOTKEY && ( HIWORD ( messages.lParam ) == GLOBAL_HOTKEY) )
                        alert("Coming only for Single Key");
```

This code works well, Only If the user selects a single key and not working when he selects multiple key combined like CTRL+F8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to isolate the virtual key out of the wHotKey value:

```
RegisterHotKey ( NULL, 
    TURN_OFF_HOTKEY,  
    HIBYTE(LOWORD(wHotKey)),          // Modifiers
    LOBYTE(LOWORD(wHotKey))           // Virtual key
);
```